# Error en consulta de búsqueda en laravel anidada

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas tardes recien hice éste método para hacer una busqueda en Laravel

```
         $Log = Log::query()               
                  
               ->orWhere('usuario','LIKE',"$usuario")              
               ->orWhere('descripcion', 'LIKE', "$descripcion")  
               ->Wherebetween('created_at',["$fecha_inicial 00:00:00","$fecha_final23:59:59"])    
               ->get();
```

Tengo los siguientes casos:

-Si busco usuario & rango de fechas (wherebetween) me muestra resultados según esos parámetros (resultado ok).

-Si busco $descripcion & rango de fechas (wherebetween) me muestra resultados según esos parámetros (resultado ok).

-Si busco por: $descripcion & $id & Wherebetween(rango de fechas), me devuelve la combinación de $descripcion & rango de fechas, no toma en cuenta el $id, me pueden orientar para poder anidar las tres? se requiere unicamente que si o si el rango de fechas sea obligatorio del resto los otros dos campos se pueden anidar o no.
Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias por su tiempo, saludos

Comment: Tendrías que aclarar cuál es el resultado que esperas con mayor precisión. También sería útil mostrar un ejemplo de los datos que tienes en BD

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ gracias finalmente como tenia mucho apuro por terminar lo resolví con otro método y con eso lo pude resolver, gracias por la intención de ayudarme, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Una vez tuve un problema similiar, desde entonces uso esta forma, prueba a ver si te soluciona el problema

```
    $Log = Log::query()               
               ->where(function($query) use ($usuario,$descripcion)
               {
                 $query->orWhere('usuario','LIKE',"$usuario")              
                 ->orWhere('descripcion', 'LIKE', "$descripcion")  
               })
               ->Wherebetween('created_at',["$fecha_inicial',00:00:00","$fecha_final23:59:59"])    
               ->get();
```

Comment: gracias por ayuda pero está igual